# Print all name of a db file

Tags: php, sqlite

i have a problem.
I try to print all of name insert in a database, but the output is this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Antonio" ["Nome"]=> string(7) "Antonio" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Paolo" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "Paolo" } array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Giorgio" ["Nome"]=> string(7) "Giorgio" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Jonny" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "Jonny" } array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "salmone" ["Nome"]=> string(7) "salmone" } array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Paolino" ["Nome"]=> string(7) "Paolino" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Maurizio" ["Nome"]=> string(8) "Maurizio" } array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "Gennarino" ["Nome"]=> string(9) "Gennarino" } array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Giallo" ["Nome"]=> string(6) "Giallo" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Leroy" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "Leroy" } array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Verdefoglia" ["Nome"]=> string(11) "Verdefoglia" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Bravo" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "Bravo" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Mondo" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "Mondo" } array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Soil" ["Nome"]=> string(4) "Soil" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Tiburzio" ["Nome"]=> string(8) "Tiburzio" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "potrt" ["Nome"]=> string(5) "potrt" } array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Creo" ["Nome"]=> string(4) "Creo" }
```

my code is this:

```
$results = $database->query('SELECT Nome FROM Studenti');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()){
 var_dump($row);
```

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: That is exactly what it should output. You get an array of associative arrays with one field. What did you expect?

Comment: Only name without (array) } [ (string) in the output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using this:

```
$results = $database->query('SELECT Nome FROM Studenti');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray())
{
    echo "Name: ". $row['Nome'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you refeer to the `nome` fiels, and you want only to see the names and not the additional information. So actually `var_dump()` isn't what you need.

**Try it with this code:**

```
$results = $database->query('SELECT Nome FROM Studenti');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()){
 echo $row["Nome"];
}
```

Var_dump gives you all information about a variable (in your case an array), also the variable `type` - the information you normally don't want to display to your user, since its nothing your user must know about. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

use fetch_assoc instead it will only provide with key value 'Name' and then you get value using foreach